# ¿Por qué arroja (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed)?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Intento editar una tabla, añadiendo llaves foráneas. Soy bastante nuevo en esto, no sé porqué funciona con unas y con otras si es lo mismo, no encuentro la diferencia que produce el error (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed)... El código es:

**Creo las tablas**

```
CREATE TABLE OrdenTrabajo(NumeroOrden INT(5) NOT NULL, Fecha VARCHAR(10), CodigoCliente INT(5), PlacaVehiculo VARCHAR(10), CodigoMecanico INT(5), Observaciones VARCHAR(300), PRIMARY KEY(NumeroOrden));
CREATE TABLE OrdenAccesorio(NumeroOrden INT(5) NOT NULL, CodigoAccesorio INT(5), PRIMARY KEY(NumeroOrden));
CREATE TABLE Accesorio(CodigoAccesorio INT(5) NOT NULL, DescripcionAccesorio VARCHAR(300), PRIMARY KEY(CodigoAccesorio));
CREATE TABLE OrdenFalla(NumeroOrden INT(5) NOT NULL, CodigoFalla INT(5), PRIMARY KEY(NumeroOrden));
CREATE TABLE Falla(CodigoFalla INT(5) NOT NULL, DescripcionFalla VARCHAR(300), PRIMARY KEY(CodigoFalla));
CREATE TABLE Mecanico(CodigoMecanico INT(5) NOT NULL, MecanicoResponsable VARCHAR(10), PRIMARY KEY(CodigoMecanico));
CREATE TABLE Vehiculo(PlacaVehiculo VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, MarcaVehiculo VARCHAR(10), ModeloVehiculo VARCHAR(10), ColorVehiculo VARCHAR(10), PRIMARY KEY(PlacaVehiculo));
CREATE TABLE Cliente(CodigoCliente INT(5) NOT NULL, NombreCliente VARCHAR(20), NitCliente INT(15), DireccionCliente VARCHAR(50), TelefonoCliente VARCHAR(10), PRIMARY KEY(CodigoCliente));
```

**Añado datos**

```
INSERT INTO OrdenTrabajo VALUES('01','10/11/2019','01','P001ABC','01','Observacion');
INSERT INTO OrdenAccesorio VALUES('01','01');
INSERT INTO Accesorio VALUES('01','Descripcion del accesorio');
INSERT INTO OrdenFalla VALUES('01','F01');
INSERT INTO Falla VALUES('01','Descripcion de la falla');
INSERT INTO Mecanico VALUES('01','Si');
INSERT INTO Vehiculo VALUES('P001ABC','Chevrolet','Aveo','Gris');
INSERT INTO Cliente VALUES('01','Elder Vielman','123456','Su casa','51328420');
```

**Edito las tablas**

```
ALTER TABLE Cliente ADD FOREIGN KEY(CodigoCliente) references OrdenTrabajo(CodigoCliente);
ALTER TABLE Vehiculo ADD FOREIGN KEY(PlacaVehiculo) references OrdenTrabajo(PlacaVehiculo);
ALTER TABLE Mecanico ADD FOREIGN KEY(CodigoMecanico) references OrdenTrabajo(CodigoMecanico);
ALTER TABLE Accesorio ADD FOREIGN KEY(CodigoAccesorio) references OrdenAccesorio(CodigoAccesorio);
ALTER TABLE Falla ADD FOREIGN KEY(CodigoFalla) references OrdenFalla(CodigoFalla);
ALTER TABLE OrdenAccesorio ADD FOREIGN KEY(NumeroOrden) references OrdenTrabajo(NumeroOrden);
ALTER TABLE OrdenFalla ADD FOREIGN KEY(NumeroOrden) references OrdenTrabajo(NumeroOrden);
```

**Al ejecutar esto último, el error es:**

Las últimas dos no presentan el error, las anteriores si...

```
MariaDB [ServicioMotriz]> ALTER TABLE Cliente ADD FOREIGN KEY(CodigoCliente) references OrdenTrabajo(CodigoCliente);
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table `serviciomotriz`.`cliente` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
MariaDB [ServicioMotriz]> ALTER TABLE Vehiculo ADD FOREIGN KEY(PlacaVehiculo) references OrdenTrabajo(PlacaVehiculo);
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table `serviciomotriz`.`vehiculo` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
MariaDB [ServicioMotriz]> ALTER TABLE Mecanico ADD FOREIGN KEY(CodigoMecanico) references OrdenTrabajo(CodigoMecanico);
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table `serviciomotriz`.`mecanico` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
MariaDB [ServicioMotriz]> ALTER TABLE Accesorio ADD FOREIGN KEY(CodigoAccesorio) references OrdenAccesorio(CodigoAccesorio);
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table `serviciomotriz`.`accesorio` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
MariaDB [ServicioMotriz]> ALTER TABLE Falla ADD FOREIGN KEY(CodigoFalla) references OrdenFalla(CodigoFalla);
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table `serviciomotriz`.`falla` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
MariaDB [ServicioMotriz]> ALTER TABLE OrdenAccesorio ADD FOREIGN KEY(NumeroOrden) references OrdenTrabajo(NumeroOrden);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.763 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [ServicioMotriz]> ALTER TABLE OrdenFalla ADD FOREIGN KEY(NumeroOrden) references OrdenTrabajo(NumeroOrden);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.725 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [ServicioMotriz]>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo tienes mal por que la idea de crear el `CONSTRAINT` de la llave foránea es:

Unir una columna de la tabla secundaria con una columna de la tabla principal que tengan:

- Mismo tipo de dato
- Misma longitud
- Idealmente que en la tabla principal sea `PK`

Por lo tanto deberías crear el cambio así:

Te dejo este ejemplo que busca explicarte:

- Como se declara la llave foránea en la tabla secundaria
- Como aplicar el `CONSTRAINT` en la tabla secundaria

**Tabla A**

```
CREATE TABLE A(
  id VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY
);
```

**Tabla B**

```
CREATE TABLE B(
  id VARCHAR(10),
  a_id VARCHAR(10),
  CONSTRAINT fk_B_A FOREIGN KEY(a_id) REFERENCES A(id)
);
```

Entonces aquello que debes observar es:

- En el constraint el valor que pasamos a la función `FOREIGN KEY()` es el nombre de `a_id` que para este ejemplo es mi llave foránea
- Posterior en `REFERENCES ....` indico nombre de la tabla principal y entre paréntesis el nombre de la llave primaria

Answer (score 3):

Sucede que estás haciendo tus referencias *al revés*.
Intentá hacer esto:

```
ALTER TABLE OrdenTrabajo ADD FOREIGN KEY(CodigoCliente) references Cliente(CodigoCliente);
ALTER TABLE OrdenTrabajo ADD FOREIGN KEY(PlacaVehiculo) references Vehiculo(PlacaVehiculo);
ALTER TABLE OrdenTrabajo ADD FOREIGN KEY(CodigoMecanico) references Mecanico(CodigoMecanico);
ALTER TABLE OrdenAccesorio ADD FOREIGN KEY(CodigoAccesorio) references Accesorio(CodigoAccesorio);
ALTER TABLE OrdenFalla ADD FOREIGN KEY(CodigoFalla) references Falla(CodigoFalla);
```

Comment: Ya puse todas en el orden que dices, y sigue dando el mismo problema. Las mismas exactamente

Comment: Al insertar una fila en "OrdenFalla", estás enviando como segundo parámetro 'F01', siendo que tu campo es de tipo "Integer". ¿Probaste modificarlo?

Answer (score 1):

El problema era el orden,

**Orden correcto**

```
ALTER TABLE OrdenTrabajo ADD FOREIGN KEY(CodigoCliente) references Cliente(CodigoCliente);
ALTER TABLE OrdenTrabajo ADD FOREIGN KEY(PlacaVehiculo) references Vehiculo(PlacaVehiculo);
ALTER TABLE OrdenTrabajo ADD FOREIGN KEY(CodigoMecanico) references Mecanico(CodigoMecanico);
ALTER TABLE OrdenFalla ADD FOREIGN KEY(CodigoFalla) references Falla(CodigoFalla); 
ALTER TABLE OrdenFalla ADD FOREIGN KEY(NumeroOrden) references OrdenTrabajo(NumeroOrden);
ALTER TABLE OrdenAccesorio ADD FOREIGN KEY(CodigoAccesorio) references Accesorio(CodigoAccesorio);
ALTER TABLE OrdenAccesorio ADD FOREIGN KEY(NumeroOrden) references OrdenTrabajo(NumeroOrden);
```