# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `axis`.`tickets` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Tags: mysql

Estoy teniendo un error de foreign key al correr mi migracion, pero no que estoy haciendo mal en mis relaciones. Es una relacion de uno a muchos entre products, y tickets de reparacion.

Un producto puede pertenecer a distintos tickets, pero cada ticket contiene solamente un producto.

Ticket:

```
public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Product::class);
    }
```

Product:

```
public function tickets()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Ticket::class);
}
```

tickets_table:

```
$table->unsignedInteger('product_id');
$table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
```

Este es el error que obtengo:

```
 SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `axis`.`tickets` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `tickets` add constraint `tickets_product_id_foreign` foreign key (`product_id`) references `products` (`id`))
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Por qué arroja (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed)?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/329846/por-qu%c3%a9-arroja-errno-150-foreign-key-constraint-is-incorrectly-formed)

Answer (score 0):

Eh visto que se pueden utilizar las relaciones de la manera que tienes pero, en mi caso, yo uso las relaciones de la siguiente manera:

```
//EN MODELO DE TICKETS:
public function products()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Product'); //Aqui va como sea que se llame tu modelo de productos, si no tienes una carpeta para los modelos entonces seria algo como: 'App\Product'
}

//EN MODELO DE PRODUCT:
public function tickets()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Ticket', 'product_id'); //Aqui como sea que se llame tu modelo de ticket
}
```

EDIT-1: Acabo de notar que estas haciendo mal la relacion en el modelo de 'Product', tu funcion `public function tickets()` esta puesta como `belongsTo`, cuando deberia ser `hasMany`, corrige eso, tal vez eso pueda ser...

EDIT-2: Aquí hay una pregunta con respuesta que quizás pueda ayudar a orientarte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46841159/laravel-hasmany-and-belongsto-parameters/46841228